# Does Ruby on Rails affect how a web page looks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

Most of the time, whenever I hit a website that looks "bubbly" in nature, and all prettified in those pastel-like colors, I think to myself, "This was probably done with Rails." And, lo and behold, after some digging into the site's information pages I discover this is actually true. So, I pose the question, not knowing much about Rails but enough about Django to understand how the database stuff works:

Does RoR have any display-specific qualities that affect how a web page looks? Or do all RoR devs naturally use the same Adobe tools to make everything look so ubiquitous?

Comment: @Louis Rhys look at the revision history.  Jeff made it CW but not sure why

Comment: oh thanks. Didn't realise the link to the revision history is different in a CW. perhaps to prevent Nick Silberstein from getting unfair reps?

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Ruby on Rails is a server side technology, so it doesn't lend any specific quality to the user visible design.  That said, it is a "trendy" technology so people who are likely to write their back-end code with RoR are likely to choose a particular "Web 2.0" style for their views.

Comment: Funny, I thought StackOverflow was a Rails site for a long time before finding out otherwise... :D

Comment: Made me laugh out loud - bookmarking this answer for my friends who keep telling me to use RoR.

Comment: *blink* Holy... Thanks for the nice feedback, I'm flattered and embarrassed that people enjoyed my answer.  I should clarify that I think RoR is great (although I use ASP.NET MVC myself), no disrespect is/was intended, I'm not a hater.  I'm not sure I understand the CW designation, but I'm still figuring out the nuances of Stack Overflow. Cheers.

Answer (score 11):

As a Ruby on Rails developer, I can tell you that most Ruby on Rails developers are passionate about their work and we pay a lot of attention to details when building websites as much backend as front end. Its not just a trend, its a way of thinking and working.

Comment: c'mon... don't be so arrogant. A lot of people are passionate about their work and can't end up with a decent design.

Answer (score 10):

No, it hasn't any display-specific qualities.

Answer (score 3):

The theory is that RoR makes that backend stuff easier, so more time can, and apparently is, spent on the front end stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Its all done with Mirrors. And CSS. :)

Rails is a very popular Web framework, it's just be coincidence that all the ones you've looked at have been rails apps.

What kind of sites have you been looking at to draw this hypothesis?

Comment: It may not be only a coincidence, but as other people say, there may be a correlation between choice of framework / attention to design. Just wondering...

Answer (score 1):

that's a funny question with a funny description :) ... bubbly!

As a madman, I develop with RoR, it's kind of rule in our area. We learn madness from the beginning, as a result of http://railsforzombies.org...

May wise men follow a wise path!

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer: NO**

However...

As a Rails developer I can say that due to the Agile nature of Rails and the speed in which you can develop web applications with Rails I do find myself having more time freed up on a project to spend *polishing* the user interface. I believe this may be a reason you often see more polished looking Rails sites.

So in my mind I believe your choice of framework can have a direct correlation to the end product that is produced!

Answer (score 0):

Rails does add some stuff to the front end. Like to every html form, it will add a hidden input element authenticity_token.

You can also tell because rails URLs and form actions will never end with suffixes like .aspx or .php or .html or .jsp, and they won't usually append ?query=book&encoding=utf8 like you see on google. And they won't usually have superlong crufties like you see on amazon (eg [http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Web-Development-Rails-Ruby/dp/1934356549/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1297922135&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356549)). Instead Rails prefers simple routing URLs. If amazon were written in rails, you might instead expect amazon.com/books/Agile-Web-Development-Rails-Ruby

So there are ways to spot a Rails app. I expect other web frameworks, especially the ones that emulate rails, would duplicate some or all of these features, so this isn't a sure-fire method, but it helps.

Comment: So, if Amazon used Ruby on Rails, they'd stop passing parameters in the url?

Comment: This is common to many of the open source CMSs that run on PHP, and also to almost any modern/well-crafted system built on apache with mod_rewrite. Nothing particularly Rails-ish here.